# save filled form in pdf file in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, editing

I would like to save a pdf file with filled out interactive form. In evince or acrobat reader, "Print to file" can create another pdf file but the form is not editable any more. Is there some way to save the edit and keep the form interactive for later editing?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: `Ctrl+S`? I think it depends on what version of evince/reader you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is "Enable Usage Rights in Adobe Reader..." - It's only available in the Acrobat 8 Professional and newer.

In Acrobat 8 Professional the feature can be found here:

```
Advanced > Enable Usage Rights in Adobe Reader...
```

This will give users of Acrobat Reader the ability to save interactive forms with their data

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020, using [evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince) (v3.36, on Ubuntu 20.04 it's just called "Document Viewer"), I can save a PDF form (just using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, e.g., saving as a different file name), and then open the new PDF again, and continue editing the form.

(Adobe [no longer supports](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) Acrobat Reader for Linux. The latest native Linux version is 9.5.5 dated from 26/04/2013.)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>While I can't say that I have tried saving an incomplete form in this manner, I will say that the vast majority of pdf forms such as this are designed **not** to be saved, and many that I have filled out have included a warning that it would not be possible to save the edited portions of them.  I thus do not believe that it is possible to save a copy of the form and have it retain its editability.</strike>

Some further googling has turned up [this PDF](http://www.sbcapcd.org/eng/DL/InteractivePDF.pdf) stating that while Acrobat can save these forms, Acrobat Reader cannot.

In addition, I found some shareware applications designed for this purpose, but none that I have found support Linux.

Comment: But I remember I can do this in Adobe Acrobat Professionals. are people supposed to not re-edit their forms once they are printed out?

Comment: Looks like you're right: after some additional searching with Google, it appears that saving is a feature of the Acrobat programs other than Reader.  I'll go ahead and strikethrough my answer now.