# Creating fillable, saveable PDF in OpenOffice.org results in garbage

Tags: pdf, openoffice-writer, adobe-acrobat

I've been creating beautiful fillable PDFs using OOo Writer under Ubuntu for a few years.  However, I've recently been asked to make them saveable rather than just printable. So, I go to my colleague's Windows computer which has Adobe Acrobat Professional 8, and following directions outlined in [Save filled form in PDF file in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/112621/save-filled-form-in-pdf-file-in-ubuntu/124804#124804).

I end up with an unreadable, unfillable document. Acrobat Reader opens it, but it's garbage. It looks like it might be a character encoding issue. The document was created using Arial under Ubuntu. I installed OOo on the Windows box and changed the font to Tahoma.

But with either font, the resulting file is a jumble of boxes and oddly placed random characters. Given that it fails with a fairly ubiquitous font, and a Microsoft specific font, I'm guessing it's not a font issue.

Until I enable the rights, the PDF is readable both with Acrobat Reader and Acrobat Pro.

Anyone else encounter the problem? If so, did you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this if other solutions do not work out https://www.fillanypdf.com/.